# Editing list Item using drop down menu bootstrap when clicking on an item

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am implementing a new language menu for my website. 
I am using the drop down menu like that :
[Language Menu 1.0](http://jsbin.com/IDehUZu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

But my issue is that with that technique I need to have several pages for each of my selected languages... I would like to be able to change the selected language like here : 
[Seleted item changing after selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066631/how-to-change-the-main-display-of-dropdown-when-an-item-is-selected-in-bootstrap)

But I would like to display in the menu all the items excepted the one selected.

I am not very comfortable with javascript (though I'm learning). I know it is easy to remove an item from a list (Found an straight forward example here : [Remove item from list with js](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/208970-remove-a-list-item/)) but I don't know how to load the javascript that is going to do that. Is it on the ready() event? Or on the onClick event of a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#changeEN').hide();
  $('.newDropdownLanguage li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#current-language').text($(this).text());
    $('.newDropdownLanguage li').show();
    $('#changeEN').show(); // Actually it should work without this line, but I don't get why it is not working.
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Don't forget to add one `<li>` for English:

```
<li><a id="changeEN" href="#">English</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited the jsbin : http://jsbin.com/IDehUZu/1/edit It is almost working. I think that the hidden item needs to be displayed after clicking on a item and then need to hide the selected item. Edit : Actually the selected item is well hidden, I just need to show the old selected item

Comment: Yes I saw that. Actually It is working, except with the English Item ! See my code http://jsbin.com/IDehUZu/4/edit