# MVC4 Bootstrap JQuery - Set Dropdown title to item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been following several posts on here about returning the value selected from a drop-down list and setting the title of the drop-down to this selection.
current: [How to change the main display of dropdown when an item is selected in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066631/how-to-change-the-main-display-of-dropdown-when-an-item-is-selected-in-bootstrap)

Ive tried several other examples but none are working for me when other scripts work fine.

Can anyone see my silly error? (I know it has to be something small)

My Dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="platform" class="control-label col-xs-2">Platform:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="pickButton" data-toggle="dropdown">                                    
                    <span id="dropdown_title">Select</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="selectionDropdown">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">IOS</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Windows Phone</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pickButton').dropdown();
    $('#selectionDropdown li').on('click', function() {
        $('#dropdown_title').html($(this).find('a').html());
    });​
});
</script>
```

Comment: have to wrapped your code inside $(document).ready??

Comment: Thanks for the comment Exception I had missed this off but the value is still not being set when selected.

Comment: your code is working...http://www.bootply.com/kDVuF98y9H

Comment: hmm the code does not work for me still and is identical when a selection is made i get the # in http://localhost:xxxx/Home/Index#. any suggestions?

Comment: just check version of js files and see console errors

Comment: no errors & jquery-1.10.2 (loaded by default in a mvc project)

Comment: strange...i think there is problem somewhere else..

Comment: Comment deleted, Code appears to have fixed itself (blame VS2013) just confirming and will give accepted answer

Comment: Sorry... didn't get you...

Comment: you were right it works now, when i tried Sept 5th it was not working for some unknown reason.

Comment: Glad that your problem solved.. great.. cheers..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code appears to have fixed itself (blame VS2013) due to no answers please see question for working code.