# Change the text of dropdown menu when an item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Based on the selection of the drop-down the text has to change in a rails app.I went through [How to change the main display of dropdown when an item is selected in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066631/how-to-change-the-main-display-of-dropdown-when-an-item-is-selected-in-bootstrap) I have added the js and tried to integrate in my app but its not working .

```html
%hearder
 %nav.navbar.navbar-job
  .container{class: "text-center"}
   %div{class: "btn-group"}
    %ul.dropdown
     I am 
     %a.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-job{"data-toggle" => "dropdown","role" => "button"}
      Select 
      %span{class: "caret",id: "dropdown_title"}
     %ul.dropdown-menu{id: "divNewNotifications"}
      %li= link_to "All Jobs", jobs_path
      - Jobcategory.all.each do |jobcategory|
       %li= link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name)
```

```html
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
$('#divNewNotifications li').on('click', function() {
    $('#dropdown_title').html($(this).find('a').html());
    });
```

**UPDATED:**

```html
%hearder
 %nav.navbar.navbar-job
  .container{class: "text-center"}
   %div{class: "btn-group"}
    %ul.dropdown
     %a.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-job{"data-toggle" => "dropdown","role" => "button"}
      Select
      %span{class: "caret",id: "dropdown_title"}
     %ul.dropdown-menu{id: "divNewNotifications"}
      %li= link_to "All Creative Jobs", jobs_path
      - Jobcategory.all.each do |jobcategory|
       %li= link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name)
     Designer
  
        
%body
 %div{id:"testing"}
  = render 'testing'
```

```html
dropdown.js

$('#divNewNotifications li').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).find('a').html());
});


$(function(){
 $("#divNewNotifications li").live('click', function(){
  $.get(this.href,null,null,"script");
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
index.js.erb

$("#testing").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("testing")) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this..

```
$('#divNewNotifications li').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

http://www.bootply.com/9KeT6fk2PM

You don't need to use `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` since the data-toggle attribute is used on the button.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply,  i have tried your code ,the text changed when the drop down menu is selected but the selected menu is a link to a page so when the page refreshes and the selected menu of text is lost and it goes back to default. Ex my index page is http://localhost:3000/ drop down menu is "All jobs" and when i select Graphic from the drop down menu its http://localhost:3000/jobs?jobcategory=Graphic  ... but its till All jobs in drop down menu

Comment: Hi , i have updated the code i am now trying with ajax , could you check the code